# AngularJS : Link jquery with angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I'm new with angular and i'm facing a problem. I try to bind my jquery DateTimePicker with angular, and i'm wondering how.
My DateTimePicker input value is a string, and i need to bind the corresponding Date Object with my angular variable.

Here is my code :

**JS** :

```
myModule.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    /* initialize current_date value */
    $scope.current_date = new Date();
}]);
```

**HTML** :

```
<input id="datetimepicker" type="text" />                        

<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
            onChangeDateTime:function(ct,$i){
                console.log(ct);
            }                       
        });
   });
</script>
```

When i select a date, on the datePicker, it fires the changeDateTime event, and the 'ct' variable is my date oject. My question is : How can i bind this 'ct' variable with my angular current_date ?
I tried with ng-model="current_date" but it doesn't work with DateTimePicker, and anyway, i need a Date Object, not a string representation of the date.

Comment: needs to be initialized in a custom directive so element exists when code is run and where you also have scope access. Can probably find an angular module for this plugin

Comment: it seems to be the good approch. Can i define a callback function in the dom and use it inside my directive to call a function in the controller ?

Comment: don't think about the dom...think about the plugin events and scope which will be available in the event callbacks. Note you need to tell angular to run digest if you update scope in external non core angular events

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to look into [`angular-bootstrap`](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), it has a lot of jQuery/bootstrap javascript written the Angular way, it is generally not recommended to use jQuery in combination with Angular.

Comment: i've already checked but the only datePicker in anguar-bootstrap doesn't support Time, and i need a Date + Time picker

Comment: @user2733521 Have you looked at something like this: https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker or this: https://rawgit.com/eight04/angular-datetime/master/demo.html ?